# I want to answer phone call through my web site,that coming to my phone. Is it possible?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phone-call

I am developing php web application for pizza shop. there are more unit in my application such as customer care, cashier. In the customer care, When customer call, I have to type telephone number manually in the textbox and search weather customer in database or not. For that I want to automated process. When customer call my phone number, I want get call to my web application and get telephone number. Is it Possible. If possible how do it. Thank you

Comment: Try searching for 'Cloud Telephone Services', there are many of them. You can integrate them into your application through their APIs and configure it based on your needs.

Comment: That will be tough to roll on your own, but you may want to look at folks like Twilio who have already done it and can give you a platform. Do make sure to check for competition and shop around.